Firestore returnes empty document but collection is not empty
I have a Firestore collection as below.

I am able to write to the collection but not able to read.
I have below code to read but it is returning empty collection.
const { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue, Filter } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

const account = require("cert.json");

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(account)
});

const db = getFirestore();

const docRef = db.collection('users').doc('uuid-string');
const doc = await docRef.get();
console.log('doc: ', doc); // Getting empty

if (doc.exists) {
   console.log('Data: ', doc.data());
}

Output of above code:
$ node app.js
doc: 
Data: 


The flag doc.exists is empty so it is going inside if condition.
I have the read write access set in the rule.
....
 match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }

I am referring to below link.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js
Similar to this question, but the answer is not applicable for me.
Firestore returns empty array for collection with documents

this might be a dump just noticed that you are querying user instead of users

No, it was a typo in the question, correction done.

could you try the modular approach from the doc instead of namespace API

Can you please provide more details on modular approach?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document
check it out click on the first tab

Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please respond using @AlexMamo

@SanuKhan I did try to use the modular approach but getting error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

@AlexMamo The database looks exactly as described in this screen capture https://i.sstatic.net/pBQfx.png

Please edit the question to show the exact output of this program.  Just copy the text into the question.  It's not clear what "getting empty" means.  It's generally not meaningful to log a DocumentSnapshot object.  You should just the DocumentSnapshot API to discover what's in the document, if it exists at all.

@DougStevenson copied the console output.

I was chatting with Doug earlier, and I think we're both at a loss at what could cause doc to output an empty string here. You might want to see if you can break on that in a debugger, to inspect the variable.

could you try with where condition instead of get, get usually works with primary key which in this case its ID of the document

Have you solved the issue?
